# Check for java.awt.Component paint rendering

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

Can I check if a java.awt.Component is actually painted without overriding `paint()`?

Let's assume I have several components added to a JFrame which is packed & visible.

Now, can I check to see which components (if any) were actually painted and rendered on the screen?

Note that `isShowing()` & `isVisible()` are not indicative here.

Comment: Not really, if it's packed and visible then it's possible for all the components to be rendered.  The question is, what are you trying to establish and why?

Comment: @ MadProgrammer it's mostly to satisfy my own curiosity. I was intrigued by several posts regarding Swing drawing mechanism. I then thought of some optimization solution and wanted to compare it to current paint mechanism.

Comment: I don't know if it will satisify you, but you could attach a `AWTListener` to the event queue (via the `Toolkit`) and monitor of `PaintEvent`s

Comment: @ MadProgrammer Thanks. it might have, but AWTListener will catch only heavyweight components' events. Swing (lightweight) painting mechanism is different and doesn't trigger on AWTListener.

Comment: I didn't think it was the different. You might consider having a look at the `RepaintManager`. You "could" supply your own to act as a proxy